# Conventions for metadata attributes in netCDF for compound data types

Tags: struct, attributes, metadata, netcdf

NetCDF allows (at least in its version 4 format based on HDF5) to create compound data types (very similar to a C struct). Each component has a label and a type and a position in the compound type. For example, for a data set of statistics, we could use the compound type defined by `[('min', 'float'), ('max', 'float'), ('avg', 'float'), ('std', 'float')]` has as its second component a `float` labeled `max`.

Now, netCDF also allows for adding metadata. These typically follow cenventions, such as the [NetCDF Climate and Forecast (CF) Metadata Conventions](http://cfconventions.org/). This is useful so that other users of the generated netCDF file can easily understand the metadata.

But I have not found conventions specifically dealing with compound data types, e.g., to give metadata specifically for one component of the compound data.

- Are there such conventions?
- If not or also, what is being used in practice?
- If this is not used, what do you advise and why? (I was thinking of using multi-line attributes, so separated by `\n`, with a component-specific label to start each line, such as `[avg]` or `#avg`.)

Comment: It really depends on who you are going to share the data with. The wider the audience, the more standard it has to be. If someone is using fortran, he/she may not be happy about custom string parsing, is someone is using the JAVA library, then already unsigned integer may cause problems. So I'd rather avoid compound types unless they really help in some regards and use groups or something simpler. The list of supported netcdf conventions is here, https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/conventions.html

Answer (score 1):

To stay within the CF conventions you could create a separate variable for each member of the compound type and use the [`ancillary_variables`](http://cfconventions.org/cf-conventions/v1.6.0/cf-conventions.html#ancillary-data) attribute to indicate that they are related:

```
netcdf test {
dimensions:
    time = 3 ;
    lat = 36 ;
    lon = 36 ;
variables:
    double time(time) ;
        time:long_name = "Time" ;
        time:standard_name = "time" ;
        time:units = "Days since 1970-01-01 00:00" ;
        time:calendar = "standard" ;
    float ctp(time, lat, lon) ;
        ctp:_FillValue = -999.f ;
        ctp:long_name = "Cloud Top Pressure" ;
        ctp:standard_name = "air_pressure_at_cloud_top" ;
        ctp:units = "Pa" ;
        ctp:cell_methods = "time: mean" ;
        ctp:ancillary_variables = "ctp_std ctp_min ctp_max" ;
    float ctp_std(time, lat, lon) ;
        ctp_std:_FillValue = -999.f ;
        ctp_std:long_name = "Cloud Top Pressure Standard Deviation" ;
        ctp_std:units = "Pa" ;
        ctp_std:cell_methods = "time: standard_deviation" ;
    float ctp_min(time, lat, lon) ;
        ctp_min:_FillValue = -999.f ;
        ctp_min:long_name = "Cloud Top Pressure Minimum" ;
        ctp_min:units = "Pa" ;
        ctp_min:cell_methods = "time: minimum" ;
    float ctp_max(time, lat, lon) ;
        ctp_max:_FillValue = -999.f ;
        ctp_max:long_name = "Cloud Top Pressure Maximum" ;
        ctp_max:units = "Pa" ;
        ctp_max:cell_methods = "time: maximum" ;
}
```

You could then add metadata as usual via the variables' attributes. For example, the [`cell_methods`](http://cfconventions.org/cf-conventions/v1.6.0/cf-conventions.html#cell-methods) attribute could be used to describe the applied statistics.

If you want to stick to the compound datatype, there is a ticket about vector quantities which might be related (although it is quite old): https://cf-trac.llnl.gov/trac/ticket/79

Comment: The suggestion that allows staying within CF is useful. The ticket about vector quantities is interesting. However, both try to shoehorn structure into the limited CF view, which ignores groups and compound data types. So while a useful reaction, this does not really form an answer.